# Multidimensional ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm simulating a supermarket, with various checkout lines, and each of them has its own queue, where the customers will be added when they finish shopping. Both customers and checkouts are clases, instantiated in the main class using Arraylists.

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList=new ArrayList<Customer>(maxCustomers);
for (i=0;i<maxCustomers;i++){
    customerList.add(new Customer(randomItems, randomArrival);
}
```

I create the checkouts in a simmilar way.

```
Arraylist<Checkout>checkoutList=new ArrayList<Checkout>(maxCheckoutLines);
for (i=0;i<maxCheckoutLines;i++){
    checkoutList.add(new Checkout());
}
```

The problem here is that I want to create another ArrayList to simulate one queue in each checkout, where I will add the Customers when they finish shopping. I don't know if I should use a multidimensional ArrayList when creating the Checkouts, and I would like to know also how to operate with it when adding the Customers.
Regards

Comment: It's usually better to use the interface List instead of ArrayList

Comment: TheEwook is saying that because it makes it easier to change your type of `List` later. Equally if the order of the list isn't important you should use the `Collection` interface so you can easily change between any collection later. So `Collection<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<Customer>()`

Comment: Also; I note you use `new ArrayList<Customer>(maxCustomers);` be aware that `maxCustomers` isn't actually the maximum. Its just the initial capacity of the `ArrayList`. It will automatically resize if you add more than that to it (think of it as an efficiency measure and nothing more)

Comment: So I will change it to List. What are its pros against ArrayList? And regarding to the maxCustomers, there will not be more Customers than that number, so it would not resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Checkout` can contain a field of `ArrayList<Customer>` that you should add the customers to.

```
public class Checkout {
    public ArrayList<Customers> custList = new ArrayList<>();
    ....

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Checkout> chkouts = new ArrayList<>();

    chkouts.add(new Checkout());
    chkouts.get(0).custList.add(new Customer());
```

Comment: I understand that with `chkouts.get(0).custList.add(new Customer());` I will add the Customer to the queue in the first checkout, is it true?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, at the moment is working this way.